# Shemot 3:12 v.s. covenant with Avraham

Tags: yetziat-mitzrayim, kabbalat-hatorah, parashat-lech-lecha, parashas-shemos

In different commentaries about the verse of [Shemot 3:12](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0203.htm#12), I've read that the entire purpose of leaving Egypt was in order that Bnei Yisrael would come to Har Sinai and accept the Torah (to serve Him on Mount Sinai).

At the berit ben habetarim (the covenant between the pieces) HaShem foretold that Bnei Yisrael would serve in a land not theirs, [Bereshit 15:13-14](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0115.htm#13), but would leave it with great possession (Birkus Gadol).

Is it possible that HaShem spoke of His Torah when he spoke of this possession (other than the gold and silver, [Shemot 3:21-22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0203.htm#21))?

---

The first commandment of the Aseret Devarim reads ([Shemot 20:2](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0220.htm#2)): I am HaShem, who have brought thee out of the land of Mizraim, out of the house of servitude. IBN Ezra explains that Bnei Yisrael was bought by Him (15:16) in order to serve HaShem ([Vayikra 25:55](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0325.htm#55)).

If the entire purpose of leaving Egypt was in order that Bnei Yisrael would come to Har Sinai and accept the Torah and serve Him, than what of that was foretold to Avraham Avinu?

I'm trying to see the connection between the prophecy (?) that was given to Avraham and the actual story of Yisrael leaving Egypt.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to glean some insight to the connection from [Ramban's explanation on Shmot 3:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=35). It's lengthy, but an important part of what he states is that regarding B'nai Yisra'el and Moses leadership, there was a sequence and cause / effect. Ramba"n states that B'nai Yisra'el would listen to Moses about the concept of being freed from Pharoah and slavery. Because who wants to continue to be enslaved under harsh conditions? However, they would not initially listen to Moses about going to the land of Cana'an. Therefore:

- You (Moshe) will bring them to receive the Torah at Mt. Sinai
- By doing this, the people will accept the yoke of God and be willing to follow His Mitzvot
- At that same time, they will believe and trust in you
- By trusting in you, they will be willing to follow you to wherever you command them

Comment: Thank you for your response; I'm going to read Ramban's explaination. I find it very intriguing to see all the different connections between the covenant made with Avraham Avinu and the covenant made with B'nai Yisra'el at Sinai.